# Finding the CPU id numbers to use with cpu sets

Tags: cgroups, cpu-architecture, multiprocessor

The man for [cpuset](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cpuset.7.html) doesn't seem to clearly list how to figure out which numbers map to which processing units. My current machine has two [Intel Xeon E5645](http://ark.intel.com/products/48768/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5645-12M-Cache-2_40-GHz-5_86-GTs-Intel-QPI)s, each of which has 6 cores and hyperthreading enabled, so I have 24 total processing units I can refer to with cpusets. My challenges are 1) determine which cpuset ID numbers map to which processor 2) determine which cpuset id numbers are paired (e.g. siblings on a core)

Are the numbers that `lscpu` outputs the same identifiers I should use to refer to cpu set processors? If so, it seems the numbers are alternated here, and this answers (1) with "evens are one processor, odds are the other processor", but I'm not sure if I'm reading it correctly.

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                24
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-23
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    6
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 44
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               2393.964
BogoMIPS:              4788.01
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              12288K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23
```

`lstopo` from the `hwloc` package seems to show me the answer to (2), and if I'm reading the man page correctly the `P#...` bits are the identifier "used by the OS", which leads me to believe these are the ones I need to pass to cpu sets. So limiting a process to cpus 0 and 12 would be allowing use of two threads on the same core, while limiting it to cpus 0 and 2 would be two threads on two different cores. Does that seem correct?

```
$ lstopo
Machine (35GB)
  NUMANode L#0 (P#0 18GB) + Socket L#0 + L3 L#0 (12MB)
    L2 L#0 (256KB) + L1d L#0 (32KB) + L1i L#0 (32KB) + Core L#0
      PU L#0 (P#0)
      PU L#1 (P#12)
    L2 L#1 (256KB) + L1d L#1 (32KB) + L1i L#1 (32KB) + Core L#1
      PU L#2 (P#2)
      PU L#3 (P#14)
    L2 L#2 (256KB) + L1d L#2 (32KB) + L1i L#2 (32KB) + Core L#2
      PU L#4 (P#4)
      PU L#5 (P#16)
    L2 L#3 (256KB) + L1d L#3 (32KB) + L1i L#3 (32KB) + Core L#3
      PU L#6 (P#6)
      PU L#7 (P#18)
    L2 L#4 (256KB) + L1d L#4 (32KB) + L1i L#4 (32KB) + Core L#4
      PU L#8 (P#8)
      PU L#9 (P#20)
    L2 L#5 (256KB) + L1d L#5 (32KB) + L1i L#5 (32KB) + Core L#5
      PU L#10 (P#10)
      PU L#11 (P#22)
  NUMANode L#1 (P#1 18GB) + Socket L#1 + L3 L#1 (12MB)
    L2 L#6 (256KB) + L1d L#6 (32KB) + L1i L#6 (32KB) + Core L#6
      PU L#12 (P#1)
      PU L#13 (P#13)
    L2 L#7 (256KB) + L1d L#7 (32KB) + L1i L#7 (32KB) + Core L#7
      PU L#14 (P#3)
      PU L#15 (P#15)
    L2 L#8 (256KB) + L1d L#8 (32KB) + L1i L#8 (32KB) + Core L#8
      PU L#16 (P#5)
      PU L#17 (P#17)
    L2 L#9 (256KB) + L1d L#9 (32KB) + L1i L#9 (32KB) + Core L#9
      PU L#18 (P#7)
      PU L#19 (P#19)
    L2 L#10 (256KB) + L1d L#10 (32KB) + L1i L#10 (32KB) + Core L#10
      PU L#20 (P#9)
      PU L#21 (P#21)
    L2 L#11 (256KB) + L1d L#11 (32KB) + L1i L#11 (32KB) + Core L#11
      PU L#22 (P#11)
      PU L#23 (P#23)
  HostBridge L#0
    PCIBridge
      PCI 14e4:163a
        Net L#0 "eth0"
      PCI 14e4:163a
        Net L#1 "eth1"
    PCIBridge
      PCI 102b:0532
    PCI 8086:2921
      Block L#2 "sda"
    PCI 8086:2926
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

there you will get each hyperthread listed like this:

```
processor       : 0
physical id     : 0
core id         : 1
```

"processor" stands for the "logical processor", what is presented to the operating system as a processor. If you have hyper threading switched on, you will see two "logical processors" per core. The "physical id" will be the processor that you can touch (you have two of them).

Here is a listing from my 1-processor 4-core system with hyperthreading:

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo|egrep "processor|core id|physical id"
processor       : 0
physical id     : 0
core id         : 0
processor       : 1
physical id     : 0
core id         : 1
processor       : 2
physical id     : 0
core id         : 2
processor       : 3
physical id     : 0
core id         : 3
processor       : 4
physical id     : 0
core id         : 0
processor       : 5
physical id     : 0
core id         : 1
processor       : 6
physical id     : 0
core id         : 2
processor       : 7
physical id     : 0
core id         : 3
```

Comment: Yes, but do you have any confirmation that these numbers are the ones used by cpu set....?

Comment: cpuset does not exist in my distribution (SUSE) which /proc/cpuinfo exists whereever there is a Linux kernel. I would not use cpuset. If you insist to, use sched_setaffinity to pin a process to a CPU, then you can use different programs to find out what CPU it is running on.

Comment: It's not that I insist, it's that my entire question is about how to figure out which IDs are correct for cpu set. Seems like you've answered the wrong question - I understand proc/cpuinfo and multiple other tools, but the complication is that I don't know how they relate to cpuset

Answer (score 2):

```
lstopo --cpuset
```

Will tell you what cpusets you should use to include each logical processor in the mask format.

You can convert that to the processor list format to check the processor numbers match.

Or if you are like me and are lazy you can do something like

```
taskset 0x00800000 grep -i Cpus_allowed /proc/self/status
```

And you'll get an output like

```
Cpus_allowed: 000,00800000
Cpus_allowed_list: 23
```

Which when I use `lstopo --cpuset` on my test machine matches

```
PU L#46 (P#23) cpuset=0x00800000
```

So you should use the number in (P#nn) when you are setting a cpuset using the list format.